# How are 可爱 and Japanese 'kawaii' related?

Tags: etymology

Did the Japanese word originate in Chinese, or was it the other way around? Or are the two words related at all?

Comment: I noticed the both Japan and Korea maintained some expressions the same as in Chinese (the meanings and pronunciations). But I don't know if this is one of the cases.

Comment: According to [Japanese Wiktionary](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%81%84%E3%81%84), they seem to be unrelated.

Comment: Related: [Which of 可爱/可愛い was exported to the other between Chinese and Japanese?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20049/which-of-%e5%8f%af%e7%88%b1-%e5%8f%af%e6%84%9b%e3%81%84-was-exported-to-the-other-between-chinese-and-japanese/20067#20067)

Answer (score 6):

No, Japanese **kawaii** is not etymologically related to Chinese 「可愛」.

---

As a very simplified explanation, Japanese **kawaii** is a native Japanese word, originally coming from a contraction of **kao** (*face*, forming the **kaw** part of the word) and **hayushi** (*flushed*, forming the **aii** part of the word). The semantic extension is as follows:

*flushed face* > *embarrassed* > *pitiable* > *lovable*

The modern Japanese spelling 「可愛い」 is completely [*jukujikun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji#jukujikun) (熟字訓); that is, none of the Chinese characters used here reflect any kind of etymology (Japanese or otherwise).

To reiterate, none of the [morphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme) which **kawaii** is composed of are Chinese in origin at all, but for the benefit of anyone who's studying Japanese and are aware of [the idea of [*kun'yomi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji#Kun%27yomi_(native_reading))], [Japanese spelling habits], and how it's a complete [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) to relate [*kun'yomi* words represented by Chinese characters] to [Chinese morphemes], the modern spelling of those Japanese words are:

- **kawaii** - 「可愛い」
- **kao** - 「顔」
- **hayushi** - 「映し」

---

**References:**

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8F%AF%E6%84%9B%E3%81%84#Japanese

Answer (score 0):

They are unrelated.

> 汉字表记可愛い为借字 (当て字)和熟字訓，且使用了愛的不规则读法。**与汉语可爱**(官话kě'ài，闽南语khó-ài)**发音相近实属巧合**。
>
> [维基词典 - 可愛い](https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8F%AF%E6%84%9B%E3%81%84#%E6%97%A5%E8%AA%9E)

Comment: Do you know why the Japanese retained some of the Chinese characters but not their meanings and pronunciations?

Comment: @r13 https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%86%9F%E5%AD%97%E8%A8%93 ？

Comment: Unrelated in pronouciation.